# Adding checkboxes in SSRS reports to filter values on a table

Tags: ssrs

I am trying to create a report that would list records but I need some way to include or exclude some values probably by using some form of option like a checkbox or a custom element in SSRS.

For example I'd have a table with the following data:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|         Name        |     Category     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         John        |     Project      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          Bob        |      Support     |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Is it possible to have checkboxes on the side that can filter out let's say just rows with "Project" as the category?

Answer (score 1):

No. We do not have Check Box with Event Trigger and etc but you can use Hacks.

First Option is the most straight forward way of doing things. but for you to implement something like Check Box Routine you would need to hide and show check boxes and tables that have data.

1. You can Use parameter in you report, where you would bind your
   category to the parameter and when user choose it then you would use
   the parameter on the Filter option of the table.

Use with Avalable Values (default: Optional)
[image: parameter]

Then
Use The parameter on Table Filter
[image]

So user can Filter the Table Category.

2. You can use Hidden and Initial Toggle State properties with some Expression to hide and Show base on some sort of Toggle. (Not preferred)

I used *Two Table,* inside **Another Table.** set ToggleItem of Each ,to the **Cell** that would do the Toggle.

**Result:**

[image: Result]

**Design:**

[image: Design]

---

**Row option:**

[image: RowOption]